# Select SQL Statement cannot read the latest user input

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net

I am new in vb.NET and SQL. I want to view the latest input in my vb.NET program. How would I do it? Where bed number is auto-increment. Currently, this do record the changes in the database but when I want to view the details the label remains empty which it should be.

This is my code:

```
 Dim SQLStatement As String = "SELECT name, age, date_of_confinement,type_of_sickness, " _
                              "type_of_IV_fluid, number_of_bottles, drop_rate " _
                              "FROM patient WHERE bednumber=1"

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

        '--read the records in database in phpmyadmin gui---
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If myReader.Read Then
            ViewInfo.lblName.Text = myReader.GetString(0)
            ViewInfo.lblAge.Text = myReader.GetString(1)
            ViewInfo.lblDate.Text = myReader.GetString(2)
            ViewInfo.lblSickness.Text = myReader.GetString(3)
            ViewInfo.lblFluid.Text = myReader.GetString(4)
            ViewInfo.lblBottle.Text = myReader.GetString(5)
            ViewInfo.lblDrop.Text = myReader.GetString(6)

            myReader.Close()
        End If
    End With
```

Thanks!

Comment: Give us some information first. Do you see a row in your table with bednumber=1? Did you trace the above code? Did the connection to the database work without errors (you should open the connection and test the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the SQL statement in this way:

```
 Dim SQLStatement As String = "SELECT TOP 1 name, age, date_of_confinement,type_of_sickness, " _ 
                              "type_of_IV_fluid, number_of_bottles, drop_rate " _ 
                              "FROM patient ORDER BY bedumber DESC"
```

This will sort the patient table on `bednumber` in descending order (so the last inserted record is on top) then get this first record (TOP 1).

Of course I suppose that `bednumber` is a numeric column with values autogenerated sequentially by the database in rough order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

For show the latest input, I will do this in my query

```
   Dim SQLStatement As String = "SELECT name, age, date_of_confinement,type_of_sickness, " _
                              "type_of_IV_fluid, number_of_bottles, drop_rate " _
                              "FROM patient WHERE badnumbre=(SELECT MAX(bednumber) from patien )"
```

I Use The Sub query for it

I Hope it run well :)